# Regex match if it doesn't have certain characters either side, but don't include those characters either side

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that matches MY_EXAMPLE, but I don't want it to match it if it has A-Z_' at one side or both of the sides.

So for example:

```
MY_EXAMPLE
(MY_EXAMPLE)
abcdefMY_EXAMPLEabcdef
'MY_EXAMPLE'
MY_EXAMPLE_
MY_EXAMPLE_EXAMPLE
HELLO_MY_EXAMPLE
MY_EXAMPLEABCDEF
```

only the first 3 should match and it should match the `MY_EXAMPLE` part only.

The best I've got so far is this:

```
[^A-Z'_]MY_EXAMPLE[^A-Z'_]
```

This matches the second and third, but it also matches the character either side which I don't, and it's also why the first one won't match because my regex also says a character has to exist either side.

Here is an image example: 
The left side is what my regex matches, the right side is what I want it to
match.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfSiV.jpg)

Comment: If you can use assertions, it would be this `(?<![A_Z'_])MY_EXAMPLE(?![A_Z'_])` https://regex101.com/r/2Oe35n/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regex needs negative look ahead and negative look behind. You can use this regex,

```
(?<![A-Z_'])(MY_EXAMPLE)(?![A-Z_'])
```

Group 1 will match only MY_EXAMPLE

Demo, https://regex101.com/r/1JVhNg/1